# Clipboard manager with favorites feature?

Tags: clipboard-manager

I am looking for a clipboard manager with favorites feature. That is, I should be able to star or mark some clipboard items as favorites. These items should never be removed from the clipboard history.

I am using Diodon currently and it does not have this feature.

Answer (score 2):

I can recommend **Parcellite** as it is not only a very sound and at the same time lightweight Clipboard Manager, but you can also save your "favorites" in its **Actions** tab.

Go to **Preferences > Actions**, and then enter a *label* for your favorite item under the **Action** column, and then go to **Command** column to simply enter your favorite text preceded by the command `parcellite` (For example; Action: my email address Command: parcellite myname@mymailserver.com)

To use your favorite text, you'll only need to press `Ctrl+Alt+A` and then choose its label (e.g. "my email address") from the popup menu, followed by the usual `Ctrl+V`, and there you have your email address instantly pasted.

Answer (score 0):

[Keepboard](http://sourceforge.net/projects/keepboard/) provides the ability to create custom groups for clipboard items. It ships with Favorites group already pre-created by default.

Answer (score 0):

[CopyQ](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ) might be an answer too.

I can be installed as follows (quoting from the project's GitHub):

> ### Debian 10+, Ubuntu 18.04+, and their derivatives
>
> Install `copyq` package.
>
> `copyq-plugins` is highly recommended. `copyq-doc` available.
>
> #### Ubuntu PPA
>
> Install and keep CopyQ always up to date by running the following
> three commands from the terminal:
>
> ```
> sudo add-apt-repository ppa:hluk/copyq
> sudo apt update
> sudo apt install copyq
> ```

Here is the relevant issue about favorites: [Favorites? · Issue #545 · hluk/CopyQ · GitHub](https://github.com/hluk/CopyQ/issues/545)

Answer (score 0):

Qlipper is a simple clipboard history manager that default installed by the lubuntu desktop. It provides a "sticky items" feature, allows you to pin copied texts.

You can install it via:
`sudo apt install qlipper`